# How can I take a percentage and turn it into a Casino multiplier (like 10 to 1, 3 to 2 etc) and then apply a certain house edge? (like 3 %)

Tags: probability

I am making a slot machine style game where a number from 0-16 in generated, and each number has the following assigned letter based off of these ranges:

1-6 : "A"
7-11 : "B"
12-14 : "C"
15-16 : "D"
0 : "E"

I already know how to convert these to a percent (amount of numbers per letter divided by 16), with "A" having a 37.5% chance, B having 25% chance etc

How can I convert these numbers to a casino-style multiplier (like $10 to $1, $8 to $2 etc) and then apply a desired house edge (like 3%)?

Comment: With an old-fashioned slot machine you put a coin in and pull the lever. Then it does it spinny thing and after it stops, it gives you zero or more coins. The number of coins depends on where each of the wheels stopped. Most combinations will give zero coins even though they may have different probabilities. For a 3% edge you just need to make sure that for every 100 coins someone puts in, on average they get 97 back. (Also, only one wheel? How is that supposed to work?)

Comment: look up _percentage to odds_ and _house edge odds_.

Comment: There are $17$ choices for number, not $16$. If you had not included $0$, then there would be only $16$. $A$ has a probability of $\frac 6{17}$, B has a probability of $\frac 5{17}$, C is $\frac 3{17}$, D is $\frac 2{17}$ and E is $\frac 1{17}$. In terms of odds, the odds of getting A is $6 : 11$, the odds of getting B is $5 : 12$, C is $3 : 14$, D is $2 : 15$ and E is $1 : 16$. And if you think about that, you should be able to spot how they are related.